# iterate through mongodb entry javascript node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to iterate through a doc during my update function

```
User.prototype.update = function(user, done){
    this.model.findOne({_id:user._id}, function(err, doc){
        console.log(doc);
        for(var i in doc){
            if(user[i] != undefined && user[i] != doc[i]){
                console.log('this value', i, user[i], user[i] === doc[i], doc[i]);
                doc[i] = user[i];
            }
        }
        console.log(doc[i]);
        //doc.save(done);
    });
}
```

however doing this catches all the functions that the model has added to the object such as _save, _done, _events, and many other fields that i dont care to check.

I also tried adding a if(user.hasOwnProperty(i)) but that doesnt work.

UPDATE: this is working pretty nicely if anyone sees a better way to go about it let me know

```
User.prototype.update = function(user, done){
    this.model.findOne({_id:user._id}, function(err, doc){
        for(var i in doc._doc){
            if(user[i] && user[i] != doc[i])
                doc[i] = user[i]
        }
        doc.save(done);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think better use toObject

Comment: you are very right good sir thank your for pointing that out. I misunderstood that entirely when i read the documentation on it I though it set the methods to save the object. thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case, query returns MongooseDocument, that's why you get properties like _doc, save and so on, you should use [lean](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) - if you use this function you get plain js object not MongooseDocument..

```
this.model.findOne({_id:user._id}).lean().exec(function(err, doc){
     // ..
});
```

Or use [toObject](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

```
this.model.findOne({_id:user._id}, function(err, doc){
    for (var i in doc.toObject()) {
       console.log(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```
keys = Object.keys(doc); // returns an array of keys

keys.forEach(function(key{
  if (typeof doc[key] !== 'function' && user[key] && doc[key] !== user[key] ) {
    // do what you want here
  }
})
```

That should get you started. If `doc[key]` or `user[key]` is an object, they [won't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) be equal. Google 'javascript object equality' to find a solution that work for you.